# How to check if Joomla is Offline

Tags: php, html, joomla3.0

I have tried searching through the site, but cannot quite find an answer.

I would like a Joomla site, which is currently offline (and being developed) to redirect to the old site located in a folder `legacy` after 10 seconds by placing the following code in the header of the offline page.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=/legacy/" />
```

What I need is an `if` condition to place that code when the site is displaying the offline page, but the admin has not logged in the frontend.

Example in pseudo code:

```
if (offline page is displayed because no privileges to view site)  
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=/legacy/" />';
```

I need to know what to put in the `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an request with curl.

If you also handle the http-status-codes correctly we receive a 403 ('cause its "forbidden" to enter the page) or an similar code.

The sourcecode will look pretty similar to this one:

```
// init curl connection
$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com/');

// execute the curl request
curl_exec($ch);

if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
  // switch by http status code
  if(url_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) === $desiredHttpCode){

    // Your code 

  }
}
// close the curl connection
curl_close($ch);
```